# Is there a way to change MongoDB _id field name in MongoEngine from $oid to $id?

Tags: mongodb, projection, mongoengine

When querying MongoDB using `mongoengine` it returns result with minor differences to what I expect. One of the important ones is `$oid` which is returned but I don't like it:

```
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5e3c0f7f284137537bf7c994"
  },
```

Is there a way to project differently in `mongoengine`? What I want is a simple id field:

```
"id": "5e3c0f7f284137537bf7c994"
```

---

**EDIT1:**
When I want to get string version of `ID` I can use `.id` to get let's say `"5e3c0f7f284137537bf7c994"`. But problem is where I want to get the whole document:

```
MyModel.objects.all()
```

This query returns a list of all documents from `MyModel`, BUT list of documents contain `$oid` rather than string version of `_id`. How should I get _id as is NOT $oid.

Comment: `.id` should return string id by default

Comment: @Valijon thank you for your note. What I want is that when I find a document it returns all fields along side _id which in the format I mentioned in the question. I need to reformat it.

Comment: did you try just `.Class.objects.get(condition).id` ?

Comment: @Valijon please take a look at the `EDIT1` section of question. Thanks.

Comment: take a look my answer

Comment: check again my response, maybe you get it interesting. If not, just ignore

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use `aggregate` method with [$toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) operator

```
pipeline = [
    {"$addFields" : {"_id" : {"$toString" : "$_id"} } }
]
data = MyModel.objects().aggregate(pipeline)
```

http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#mongodb-aggregation-api

**Note:** This won't return `MyModel` instance, you lose `mongoengine` features

But, if you do not want lose features (works only for `to_json`):

```
from bson import json_util, son
..

class MyModel(Document):
    content = StringField(required=True)
    #setup your attributes

    def to_json(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raw = self.to_mongo()
        tmp = [(k, str(raw[k]) if k == "_id" else raw[k]) for k in raw]
        return json_util.dumps(son.SON(tmp), *args, **kwargs)

...

# This returns <class 'mongoengine.queryset.queryset.QuerySet'>
data = MyModel.objects()

print(data[0])
print(data[0].to_json())

print(data.to_json())
print("[%s]" % ",".join([foo.to_json() for foo in data]))

----

MyModel object
{"_id": "5e400e737db7d0064937f761", "content": "foo"}

[{"content": "foo", "_id": {"$oid": "5e400e737db7d0064937f761"}}, {"content": "bar", "_id": {"$oid": "5e400e737db7d0064937f762"}}]
[{"_id": "5e400e737db7d0064937f761", "content": "foo"},{"_id": "5e400e737db7d0064937f762", "content": "bar"}]
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit, it seems a better approach. Just a side note, I think `to_json` method needs to be indented to be a member of `MyModel` class :)